# Excel, IF Greater function, Time/date offset

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns,

Column A has date and time(date shows within the cell), Column B has just time. Column C contains the offset date that pertains to column B. How can I view when col A times surpass that of times in Col B?

Currently I use but it take into account that times may be on different dates:

```
=IF(A2-INT(A2)>B2,"yes","no")
```

(column C here is the yes or no, Col D is the offset 1 or 0)

[image]

I run into trouble when I have times like 3pm in col A, and 1:00 am  in col B (with an offset of 1), excel thinks that Col A is greater because I do not know how to include the offset date within this formula.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Update**:

[image]

**Update 2:**

[image]

**Changing to include dates

```
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+---+
| 16/04/19 09:06:19 | 00/01/00 14:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/20 02:00:54 | 00/01/00 02:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:20:58 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:01:06 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:50:02 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:28:07 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:28:09 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:24:21 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:21:22 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:21:22 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 14:15:01 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:15:15 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:10:12 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:13:38 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:34:33 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:28 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:28 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:34:32 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:29 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:29 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:34:36 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:35 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:33:35 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:30:54 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:29:31 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:29:31 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:29:27 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:28:39 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:28:39 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:13:32 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:15:50 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:52:00 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:06:51 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:12:32 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:10:50 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:10:50 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:12:16 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:10:54 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:10:54 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:12:49 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:11:17 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:11:18 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:22:45 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:14:49 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:14:50 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:01:49 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:00:11 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:00:12 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:34:56 | 00/01/00 22:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/20 02:06:59 | 00/01/00 06:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:06:11 | 00/01/00 06:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:31:19 | 00/01/00 07:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:12:02 | 00/01/00 07:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:49:22 | 00/01/00 07:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:40:22 | 00/01/00 07:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:51:30 | 00/01/00 02:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:39:23 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:00:30 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:06:55 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:42:55 | 00/01/00 01:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:33:33 | 00/01/00 01:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:14:59 | 00/01/00 01:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:31:18 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:16:24 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:29:21 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 09:39:37 | 00/01/00 14:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:30:59 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:30:56 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 13:24:08 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 13:24:06 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:04:43 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:03:00 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:53:35 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:52:53 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:43:50 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:43:31 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:30:40 | 00/01/00 02:00:00 | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 19:00:55 | 00/01/00 21:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:39:52 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:40:08 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:39:52 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:40:08 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:39:57 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:43:16 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:24:57 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:32:01 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:28:08 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:23:37 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:23:38 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:20:32 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:17:40 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:17:40 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:20:43 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:16:51 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:16:51 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:20:29 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:16:21 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:16:21 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:20:38 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:18:57 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:18:57 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:16:55 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:58:04 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:58:36 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:37:35 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:41:44 | 00/01/00 09:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:12:18 | 00/01/00 09:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:10:43 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:25:48 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:10:43 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:25:48 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:46:58 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:50:52 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:32:01 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:39:27 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:11:27 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:10:49 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:10:50 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:35:46 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:33:14 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:33:15 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:33:37 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:32:50 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:32:50 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:37:17 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:34:43 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:34:44 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 14:07:25 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 14:09:09 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 14:07:25 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 14:09:08 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:41:42 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:41:04 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:41:04 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:41:43 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:46:33 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:41:43 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:46:33 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:39:54 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:39:14 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:39:15 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:27:39 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 21:27:48 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:34:45 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:26:05 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:28:22 | 00/01/00 22:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 19:31:37 | 00/01/00 22:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 22:55:39 | 00/01/00 02:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:02:38 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:01:07 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:01:06 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:29:51 | 00/01/00 05:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:29:38 | 00/01/00 05:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:29:37 | 00/01/00 05:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:31:15 | 00/01/00 03:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:31:14 | 00/01/00 03:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:48:59 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:48:58 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:47:07 | 00/01/00 10:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:41:44 | 00/01/00 10:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:37:05 | 00/01/00 02:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:03:53 | 00/01/00 02:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:01:30 | 00/01/00 06:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:47:35 | 00/01/00 06:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:05:45 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:05:00 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:10:18 | 00/01/00 06:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:51:56 | 00/01/00 06:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:30:57 | 00/01/00 03:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:30:56 | 00/01/00 03:30:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 19:09:46 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/20 00:35:26 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:33:38 | 00/01/00 03:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:09:31 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:01:33 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:45:44 | 00/01/00 02:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:18:19 | 00/01/00 02:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:46:48 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:46:40 | 00/01/00 05:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:19:40 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:11:28 | 00/01/00 00:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:32:22 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:32:20 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:05:13 | 00/01/00 22:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/20 00:11:16 | 00/01/00 04:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 08:09:31 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:09:27 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:12:11 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:31:16 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:30:49 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 10:02:28 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:38:59 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:13:04 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:07:51 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:17:17 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:16:25 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 13:14:07 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 13:14:02 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:03:21 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:01:56 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:36:04 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:14:03 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:10:45 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:07:41 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:07:37 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:12:43 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:10:00 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:07:03 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:06:11 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:23:18 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:21:45 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:22:09 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:08 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:45 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:54 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:54:04 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:54:22 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:54:39 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:55:08 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:36 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:27 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 08:53:19 | 00/01/00 18:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:06:38 | 00/01/00 16:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 14:04:26 | 00/01/00 21:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 12:56:21 | 00/01/00 21:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:31:40 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:31:29 | 00/01/00 01:30:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 16:46:11 | 00/01/00 00:45:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:20:33 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:06:40 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:33:52 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:32:11 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:32:18 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:31:56 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:39:33 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:31:39 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:28:03 | 00/01/00 21:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:06:14 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:05:52 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:18:31 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:18:04 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:06:27 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:06:09 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:12:30 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:09:35 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:13:15 | 00/01/00 01:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:13:14 | 00/01/00 01:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:08:58 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 17:54:48 | 00/01/00 23:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:26:38 | 00/01/00 21:00:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:04:38 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 20:28:58 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 20:28:57 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 20:44:13 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 20:44:11 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:35:52 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:34:07 | 00/01/00 22:30:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 16:46:18 | 00/01/00 00:45:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 16:46:10 | 00/01/00 00:45:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:39:46 | 00/01/00 22:35:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:32:56 | 00/01/00 22:35:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:35:04 | 00/01/00 22:35:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:31:25 | 00/01/00 22:35:00 | no      | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:34:46 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 18:33:31 | 00/01/00 00:00:00 | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:14:50 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:30:12 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:42:14 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 17:09:12 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 22:14:27 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:25:21 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 01:29:15 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:06:39 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:38:50 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 06:00:58 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 15:35:57 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:51:48 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 12:01:03 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:23:17 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:10:43 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 21:25:48 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| N/A               |                   | #VALUE! | 1 |
| N/A               |                   | #VALUE! | 1 |
| N/A               |                   | #VALUE! | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:23:19 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 22:06:20 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 22:54:13 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 20:28:24 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 23:38:42 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 18:54:03 |                   | yes     | 0 |
| 16/04/19 09:03:24 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 09:04:54 |                   | yes     | 1 |
| 16/04/19 15:04:55 |                   | yes     | 0 |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+---+
```

**Expected Results:**

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+-----+---+
| 16/04/19 09:06:19 | 00/01/00 14:00:00       | No  | 0 |
| 16/04/20 02:00:54 | 00/01/00 02:00:00       | Yes | 1 |
| 16/04/20 02:20:58 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | No  | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:01:06 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | Yes | 1 |
| 16/04/20 03:50:02 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | Yes | 1 |
| 16/04/19 03:28:07 | 00/01/1900  18:00:00 PM | No  | 0 |
| 16/04/20 03:28:09 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | Yes | 1 |
| 16/04/19 23:24:21 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | No  | 1 |
| 16/04/19 00:21:22 | 00/01/00 03:00:00       | No  | 1 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+-----+---+
```

New update:

[image]

Comment: That copy and paste data was much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INT($A$2)+E2+B2
```

That would be your time from B2 combined with the "offset date"  from E2 and referencing the original date in A2.  using that you should be able to make straight comparison with column A.

```
=IF(A2>INT($A$2)+E2+B2,"yes","no")
```

Column A is your date and time
Column B is your time with no date
Column E is you "offset date" in days
Cell A2 is the base date you offset from.

A more verbose method if you prefer working with date and time functions:

```
=Date(Year($A$2),Month($A$2),Day($A$2)+E2)+B2
```

That would give you the time with the offset date included and then your "yes/no" if statement becomes:

```
=IF(A2>Date(Year($A$2),Month($A$2),Day($A$2)+E2)+B2,"yes","no")
```

Proof of concept:

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: Am i supposed to use the first formala first in B2 and down and then apply your 2nd formula?

Comment: no, just replace your IF then statement,  you would create a circular loop if you put the formula in B2 as the formula references B2.  If you wanted to you could put the first formula in a helper column off to the side somewhere and see how it build ups the date time value.

Comment: `=IF(A2>INT(A2)+D2+B2,"yes","no")` doesnt seem to be working.  , A being time and date, D being either 0 or 1, and B being time to see if greater or not. Im getting a no for every row.

Comment: Did you paste the formula into C1 or into C2?

Comment: C2, ill update question with a picture, Maybe because the dates in A change (from the 19th to 20th)

Comment: can you change the format of column A and B temporarily to yy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss and repost your screen shot?  Just trying to verify no hidden information is not being displayed.

Comment: Hold on...3AM the following day (ie offset day 1) is greater than ANY time of the current day.   If you want to know if you "TIME" on a given date is before or after a SET TIME that is something completely different

Comment: im going to repost the screenshot.  The current day may be on T though, so its not always greater, ex: Row 4 should be Yes because the date is the 20th for that cell.

Comment: OK you have a problem with your original question.  you said your offset date pertained to column B.  It actually looks like your offset date pertains to column A.  When the date in the current row is  X number of day after the 19th in this case, X is 1 and X is your offset date.  it has nothing to do with your time in B

Comment: Also instead of a screen shot for your last post, could you please use [this site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)(or one like it) to convert your spreadsheet data into text in your question.  That way I and other can copy the text into our own speadsheets to test

Comment: I used that site and updated question.  With your new solution still seems to not be working. If I change a row 8 to 11:00 PM I get a yes when in reality 3 am is greater.

Comment: `=if(Time(hour(A2),minutes(A2),Seconds(A2))>B2,"yes","no")` gave me #NAME, so i used the next one

Comment: accidently put S on the end of minute and second.  formula updated.  FYI, Its important when you post the data, that you include the date so people know what they are actually dealing with in a cell.

Comment: Updated the post to include dates.

Comment: I recommend you post your data with column A showing the date and time, column B showing your time, and column C showing you expected results.  Seeing the expected results may clear up a misunderstanding in the description

Comment: Check expected results in the description

Comment: Looked at your expected results, and they line up with the formula that uses MOD()  which should be the same at the formula you tried that gave you the names error.  Try those formulas again and if they do not work tell me the case where they do not.

Comment: Hi Ed, it works great except for the time where col A on previous day is lesser then 3 am on the next day (highlight in red). Check the new added pic

Comment: in your post with two columns of yes and no which is the expected results?

Comment: C is expeected, D is your Mod formula `=if(MOD(A2,1)>B2,"yes","no")`

Comment: do you have somewhere on your sheet that you state the date you are offsetting from is the 19th? or conversely will the value in A2 always be the date you are offsetting from?

Comment: A2  is always the date offsetting I believe.

Comment: Yes no problem.sorry for the late reply

Comment: updated the answer.  The way you were offsetting the date and the way you were checking your times was not the way I would have approached it so it lead to some confusion on my part.  Good luck with the rest of your sheet.

Comment: `=INT($A$2)+E2+B2` gives me a decimal. `=IF(A2>INT($A$2)+E2+B2,"yes","no")` seems to get me the results im looking for. Is this the one you wanted me to use? However I am getting issues on row 6, perhaps because my year says 00/01/1900 (I manually edited this one from my data; view expected results) , I get #Value, is this a formatting error?

Comment: the date in be should display as 0/1/0 I believe just like the rest.dont enter a date portion just enter 23:00 or 08:00.  the first formula is just going to give you a date added to your time,  The second formula is doing the yes and not comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by yes/no and not the comparison? Am I supposed to use both the first to formulas? Or just one? I want a comparison and a yes or no.

Comment: I just woke up and made a typo.  That should have read "The second formula is doing the yes and _NO_ comparison"  Just use the second formula.